# Devexpress asp grid vew. При апдейте по таймеру появляется надпись Загрузка

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

На странице 2 update panel. По таймеру одна из них обновляется. В другой находится GridView. И в момент апдейта другой панели, на гриде появляется надпись "Загрузка..."